# Facebook like social plugin shows error after pressing like

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I am using facebook social plugin "like" button in my android app. For implementing I have used android webview to load the URL that obtained while clicking "Get Code" from the URL http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/. The problem is that some times after clicking the like button it shows text "Error" in Red color. And if we click on that it displays a dialog says Warning: ... Below I am adding the image which contain the Error and Waring (took from the desktop Firefox).

[image]

**Please let me know any one has faced the same issue, and how to solve it?**

Thanks in advance

@nish

Answer (score 0):

The **content** of the message you're trying to share through the Like button is flagged as spam. You should recheck the URLs that are your message contains.

Here's what Facebook says about this message:
https://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=18347337130

Comment: I am using like button social plugin to like a facebook sample page created myself using my facebook profile. Also its working some times, some times shows error. What may be the problem?